# How to use pandas to create pivot tabel with empty cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following table

```
     tax             rate Invoice No.
  GST/HST             NaN         NaN
      NaN             NaN         NaN
      NaN           5.00%         NaN
      NaN             NaN      100000
      NaN             NaN      100001
      NaN             NaN      100002
      NaN             NaN      100003
      NaN             NaN      100004
      NaN             NaN      100005
```

how do I use pivot to produce a pivot table like this:

```
Invoice No.           tax         rate
    100000        GST/HST        5.00%
    100001        GST/HST        5.00%
    100002        GST/HST        5.00%
    100003        GST/HST        5.00%
    100004        GST/HST        5.00%
    100005        GST/HST        5.00%
```

Answer (score 0):

you need forward fill(`ffill()`) and `dropna()`

```
out=df.ffill().dropna().iloc[:,[2,0,1]]
#df.ffill().dropna().loc[:,['Invoice No.','tax', 'rate']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

OR

use forward fill and backword fill and then drop duplicates:

```
out=df.ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates().iloc[:,[2,0,1]]
```

output of `out`:

```
   Invoice No.  tax         rate
3   100000.0    GST/HST     5.00%
4   100001.0    GST/HST     5.00%
5   100002.0    GST/HST     5.00%
6   100003.0    GST/HST     5.00%
7   100004.0    GST/HST     5.00%
8   100005.0    GST/HST     5.00%
```

**Note:** Also the iloc and loc in the solution are completely optionaly you can also remove them if not needed